# What is the method to correct lightness for an image using PIL or Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am looking to see how to use OpenCV or another library for colour correction of an image.
Ideally I should be able to choose a fixed area of the image, take its RGB values and then adjust the whole image so that these RGB values match a standard. This fixed area will be a brown piece of card. Similar to gray cards in photography. This card will always be in the same area of the image.

I have several cameras that seem to give slightly different exposure or illuminate of an image.

For example, the RGB should be 39,28,26. If it comes out as 42,28,26 then 3 should be subtracted from the R channel for the whole image etc.

I am happy to convert to LAB colour space to adjust the lightness level if this seems easier?

Does anyone have any ideas? It is similar to how lightroom works to compensate for Gray card images.

So far I have tried delving into Opencv and PIL but have not been successful in finding any correct methods. 
I have been able to get the value of the RGB channels of the card in the image. But not adjust these values.

```
img = Image.open("data/sample_image.tif")
pixels = img.load()

#get the R value of the pixel at x=2400, y=2400
pixels[2400, 2400][0]
```

Comment: Why brown rather than grey? Any sample images please? Are you sure your algorithm is legitimate - normally rather than subtract say 3, from every pixel, the lower and upper bounds are stretched to 0..255? Have a read here... https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/llmps-scb/article.pdf

Comment: You can use the principles and equations from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/, which matches one image to another. Just replace one image with your standard values

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell thank you for your response. I have posted mock sample pictures in my answer below.. I think one of the suggestions of using LAB colour space could be the winner.

Comment: @fmw42 I think you have answered my question! I have used your tutorial and created a version which seems to work quite well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Brightness and contrast can be adjusted using alpha (α) and beta (β), respectively. The expression can be written as

[image]

OpenCV already implements this as [`cv2.convertScaleAbs()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs), just provide user defined `alpha` and `beta` values. I'm not sure how to adjust it based on the RBG values matching a standard

---

**Before (left), After (right)**

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')

alpha = 1.95 # Contrast control (1.0-3.0)
beta = 25 # Brightness control (0-100)

adjusted = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

cv2.imshow('original', image)
cv2.imshow('adjusted', adjusted)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @fmw42 may have answered my question as a comment.

I followed the link suggested: [Pyimage Search Colour Transfer](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/) and edited it to be used in an IDE, Juypter Notebook. I also changed it so that it read the cropped section of my image as the source (Ideal Lightness Image) and cropped section as Target (Image with wrong lightness).
I then found the adjustment necessary using these two cropped images & then applied it to the whole image.

Mockup Source Image (Ideal Lightness)
[image: Source Image]
Mockup Target Image (Wrong Lightness, to be fixed)
[image: Target Image]

```
#import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2


def color_transfer(source, target):
    source = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype("float32")
    source_crop = cv2.cvtColor(source_c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype("float32")
    target = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype("float32")
    target_crop = cv2.cvtColor(target_c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype("float32")

#compute color statistics for the source and target images
    (lMeanSrc, lStdSrc, aMeanSrc, aStdSrc, bMeanSrc, bStdSrc) = image_stats(source)
    (lMeanSrc_c, lStdSrc_c, aMeanSrc_c, aStdSrc_c, bMeanSrc_c, bStdSrc_c) = image_stats(source_crop)
    (lMeanTar_c, lStdTar_c, aMeanTar_c, aStdTar_c, bMeanTar_c, bStdTar_c) = image_stats(target_crop)
    (lMeanTar, lStdTar, aMeanTar, aStdTar, bMeanTar, bStdTar) = image_stats(target)

#subtract the means from the target image
    (l, a, b) = cv2.split(target) #Split target image into l,a,b channels. 
    l -= lMeanTar_c #Subtract Mean value of cropped Target image
    #a -= aMeanTar_c
    #b -= bMeanTar_c

    #scale by the standard deviations
    l = (lStdTar / lStdSrc) * l #std deviation of whole target image divided by source image
    #a = (aStdTar / aStdSrc) * a
    #b = (bStdTar / bStdSrc) * b

    #add in the source mean
    l += lMeanSrc_c #Add the mean of the cropped image onto the Lightness. 
    #a += aMeanSrc_c
    #b += bMeanSrc_c

    #clip the pixel intensities to [0, 255] if they fall outside
    #this range
    l = np.clip(l, 0, 255) #ensure Lightness is within 0-255 boundaries. 
    #a = np.clip(a, 0, 255)
    #b = np.clip(b, 0, 255)


    #merge the channels together and convert back to the RGB color
    #space, being sure to utilize the 8-bit unsigned integer data
    #type
    transfer = cv2.merge([l, a, b])
    transfer = cv2.cvtColor(transfer.astype("uint8"), cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

    #return the color transferred image
    return transfer

def image_stats(image):
    """
    Parameters:
    -------
    image: NumPy array
        OpenCV image in L*a*b* color space
    Returns:
    -------
    Tuple of mean and standard deviations for the L*, a*, and b*
    channels, respectively
    """
    #compute the mean and standard deviation of each channel
    (l, a, b) = cv2.split(image)
    (lMean, lStd) = (l.mean(), l.std())
    (aMean, aStd) = (a.mean(), a.std())
    (bMean, bStd) = (b.mean(), b.std())

    # return the color statistics
    return (lMean, lStd, aMean, aStd, bMean, bStd)
```

Then Read in Images:

```
target = cv2.imread("data/IssueImage.jpg")
y=2400
x=2400
h=500
w=300

target_c = target[y:y+h, x:x+w]
source = cv2.imread("data/Good_Image.jpg")
source_c = source[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Run Code

```
def show_image(title, image, width = 1000):
    # resize the image to have a constant width, just to
    # make displaying the images take up less screen real
    # estate
    r = width / float(image.shape[1])
    dim = (width, int(image.shape[0] * r))
    resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # show the resized image
    cv2.imshow(title, resized)


# transfer the color distribution from the source image
# to the target image
transfer = color_transfer(source, target)

# check to see if the output image should be saved

# show the images and wait for a key press
show_image("Source", source)
show_image("Target", target)
show_image("Transfer", transfer)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This seems to work quite well. Though I have made changes to the code such as using standard deviation of whole image but mean of cropped image... This could mean that I am "abusing" the way this should work and not give exact results.

Images do not appear exactly the same when I do it on my real images but quite close.

I am posting here in case anyone else has a similar issue. But also in case anyone can spot any glaringly obvious issue in my code.

Thank you

I also tried the flower pictures example on this thread.
I used the darker image as the target and lighter as source (ideal lightness).
[image: Flower Comparison]
The left image is ideal, middle is test image, right is test image adjusted to be same as left.

This seems to work but you will notice that it is a lot less vibrant.

Comment: I think the main issue is that I am subtracting Lightness as if it is a Linear relationship when I do not think it is. 
So I am losing highlights & lowlights.

Comment: Or it is because I am subtracting a mean lightness when I should somehow scale the min and max lightness of the source image to the target